# Web Audio API latency on Android

Tags: android, audio, web

I can only find one similar question to this on SO and it doesn't have an answer, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this!

I'm using the Web Audio API in my Intel XDK project but have found that although it works without any latency in desktop Chrome and on iPad (presumably iPhone too although I can't test this), there is very noticeable latency on Android - by latency I mean a delay of around 300ms between user initiation of a sound and playback.  It's a consistent delay and affects all sound generated through the Web Audio API.

I was wondering whether there's some sort of parameter to set the latency?  Usually it's set by how slow the processor is (i.e., slower processor = bigger buffer) but I have no idea how the Web Audio API actually works on that level.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

var bgs=[];var samps=[

  'sound/ting.mp3',
  'sound/ratchet1.mp3',
  'sound/blip.mp3',
  'sound/blipback.mp3',
  'sound/TelTing1.mp3',
  'sound/TelTing2.mp3',
  'sound/TelTing3.mp3',
  'sound/TelTing4.mp3',
  'sound/TelDialReturn.mp3',
  'sound/TelDialStop.mp3',
  'sound/TelDialSlow2.mp3',
  'sound/sea1.mp3'

];

var bufferLoader;

window.onload=function(){

  bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,samps,
    finishedLoading
    );

  bufferLoader.load();

  function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
  debug("Audio Loaded")
  soundloop=1;
  for(i=0;i<samps.length;i++){bgs[i]=bufferList[i]}
  play(0)
  }
}

var sourceA = null;
var gainNodeA = context.createGain()

function play(x) {
  sourceA = context.createBufferSource();
  sourceA.buffer = bgs[x];
  sourceA.connect(gainNodeA);
  gainNodeA.connect(context.destination)
  gainNodeA.gain.value=1;
  sourceA.start(0);
}
```

Comment: It is now Oct 2017 and I am still seeing that 300ms lag in Chrome or the generic "Internet" browser on my Android 6.0.1 Galaxy Tab S tablet.

Comment: Same latency for me when I play sounds in my webapp (built with Cordova 7.1.0) on a device. I get at least 300ms delay, but sometimes it's worst. Tested on : [Samsung J3 - Android v5] [Lenovo Tablet - Android v5] [Huawei - Android v7] [LG - Android v7] [iPhone6s - iOS11]. On each devices, there is a delay. I also tried to run on each devices some famous apps and games found on Stores. The same problem occurs most of time. There is a delay between image and sound playing.

Comment: I would like to clarify: It is understandable to have some (even quite noticeable) latency if a sound is to be played immediately -- after all the system needs time to process it. However, the baffling 300ms delay in producing the output happens when the audio buffer was pre-scheduled WAY AHEAD of time (e.g. 2 secs ahead) and still there is this fixed delay of ~300ms for the output to be heard. This is clearly a serious BUG in Chrome, instead of some Android OS/hardware issues.